# Prolog: Passing Implicit Parameter / Predicated Evaluation

Tags: prolog, parameter-passing, swi-prolog

I am looking for a reliable way to pass an implicit parameter among predicates, e.g.,

```
p(Context, Args) :- goal(Args).
```

where `goal(Args)` should be expanded to something like `interpret(Context, goal, Args)`.

However, since I don't know whether a term will be evaluated as a goal or used as data, I'd like to attach *Context* to *goal* as extra data without modifying its actual structure.

Is there any way to do this?

Also, I'd need some way to hook into the evaluation of a term, then fetch its context and call interpret.

Any Ideas?

I am using SWI Prolog, a portable solution would be fine, but is not required.

Edit:

In pseudocode, what I am roughly looking for is the following:

```
term_expansion((Head :- Body), (Head :- Body)) :-
   arg(1, Head, Context),

   forall T: CompoundTerm in Body =>
       set_term_attribute(T, context, Context).

on_evaluate(T) :-
  get_term_attribute(T, context, Context) -> interpret(Context, T) ;
  call(T).
```

Comment: Your example does not expand anything: Instead, relate `Body0` to a new body that denotes the expanded version.

Comment: It's not supposed to expand anything, term_expansion is just used as a hook to attach a context to a term, internally.

Comment: You need to make the context explicit, for example as an additional argument or by rewriting the term to contain the context. Prolog terms are not evaluated in the sense you are suggesting. They are only terms and stand for themselves.

Comment: Well, what I was trying to convey is that I want to intercept term evaluation, i.e., "calling" of terms. How that works internally, I don't know. That's the point of my question.

Again: I can't simply rewrite any term, only terms used as goals, otherwise I would also rewrite stuff like X is 1+2, which does not need the context. 

Maybe I need to rephrase the question.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that in Prolog. You will likely be better off by meta-interpreting your code in whatever way you like, carrying the context or whatever you actually need with you. Regarding terminology, it will help to distinguish between goals and their arguments when rephrasing your question.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I will use my alternative approach then.

If you like, feel to edit my post to correct my wording, I don't really know how to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the important predicates `term_expansion/2` and `goal_expansion/2`.

They allow you to *rewrite* clauses at compilation time, and these or similar constructs are supported by all serious Prolog systems to provide an expansion mechanism for Prolog code.

Definite clause grammars (see [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information) are often implemented using such mechanisms. In fact, to pass around a context, DCG notation is itself often already sufficient, so you may not even have to rewrite the code yourself in your use case.

See the [**DCG resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for hinting at goal_expansion. However, in my example, how do I get access to "Context" in "goal_expansion" without previously modifying the structure of "goal"?
I don't know which terms I can safely expand, i.e., terms which are used as goals only and not as data.

Comment: In the *expansion*, you can also insert dynamic checks that distinguish the cases, so that at run-time it will be clear what to do. Note that there is no requirement that each goal be expanded to exactly one goal: You can substitute several goals for one, and let others vanish. All considered, term and goal expansion will likely give you enough flexibility to produce the desired final program. Do what you can at compilation time, and defer the rest to dynamic checks at run-time.

Comment: That (alone) won't work in general. Because I have no way of knowing whether T in term_expansion(T, _) is used as a goal or a data term. In the latter case, expansion could break subsequent goals. That is why I'd like to associate additional information with T without alternating its structure. Of course, I could mark terms for expansions, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Please consider how term expansion works and how Prolog code is represented as Prolog terms: When expanding rules, i.e., terms of the form `Head :- Body`, you need only to expand the *goals* in `Body`. No need to expand further than that. Surely this can become complex for meta-arguments, i.e., arguments that denote goals themselves, but in simple cases a static expansion of only the goals will suffice. Start by implementing a relation `body0_body/2` that relates a clause body to its expansion. For example, write a rule for expanding a conjunction, a term of the form `(A,B)`.

Comment: I know how to expand terms, I have already done that. I know how terms are represented in Prolog. Actually, I have a use case, where I have to transform the Head as well, but that's beside the point.

"simple cases a static expansion of only the goals will suffice"
well, I want to deal with all cases. That's the entire point.

Please consider the actual contents of my question.

Comment: I have added my comment to the question and hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Use a Logtalk parametric object. You can use this solution with twelve Prolog systems, including SWI-Prolog. For example:

```
:- object(foo(_Parameter1, _Parameter2)).

    :- public(p1/1).
    p1(Parameter1) :-
        parameter(1, Parameter1).

    :- public(p2/1).
    p2(Parameter2) :-
        parameter(2, Parameter2).

:- end_object.

?- foo(1,2)::p1(P1).
P1 = 1.

?- foo(1,2)::p2(P2).
P2 = 2.
```

The parameters are **logical variables**, with all the benefits and potential that entails. The parameters are implicitly shared by all object predicate clauses. In SWI-Prolog, you can even use dicts for parameter values.

It's also easy to provide *default* parameter values. For example:

```
:- object(foo, extends(foo(a,b))).

:- end_object.

?- foo::p1(P1).
P1 = a.

?- foo::p2(P2).
P2 = b.
```

You can find several examples of using parametric objects in the Logtalk distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Interesting as it is, for my project, I have my own DSL and I don't intend to mix my project with LogTalk or any other object-oriented system. 
I am looking for a rather specific solution, I edited my answer.